# Charge plugin cannot end subscription

Tags: plugin-charge

Craft 2.x using latest Charge plugin...

When ending a subscription using the Charge area of the control panel I'm unable to  end the subscription because I get the error:

```
Page Not Found
Unable to resolve the request "site".
```

I can't figure out where the route "site" is coming from. Does anyone know?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Sorry for asking this as an "answer", I don't have the reputation required to comment.

Comment: Nope. I contacted the developer and got no joy. If we weren't switching to Craft Commerce on this project I'd update the plugin myself.